# How to make a Node.js 'urllib' request with blocking until receive a response

Tags: node.js, get, urllib

I have a NodeJS app that should send GET requests to a server and I'm using 'urllib' module.

This is my urllib app as a module:

```
const httpClient = require("urllib");

module.exports.postToURL = async (params) => {
  try {
  
    const user = params.user;
    const pass = params.pass;

    const uri = params.url;

    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      digestAuth: `${user}:${pass}`,
    };
     
    process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0; //--insecure, curl param

    httpClient.request(uri, options).then(function (result) {
     
      return result.data.toString();
    }).catch(function (err) {
 
      return '{"error": True}';
    });

  } catch (error) {

    return '{"error": True}';
  }
}
```

I'm using this module in a simple NodeJS script like this:

```
const { postToURL } = require('./post-to-url'); // my urllib module name
    
var response = postToURL({
    user: "username",
    pass: "password",
    url: 'https://....?some params...'
});
console.log("response received- > " + JSON.stringify(response));
```

I've received successfully response from server, but to late.... I want the script to wait for the server answer and then proceed to the execution of the next instruction, because I need to verify that answer first.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use `await`? Why should it *block*?

Comment: VLAZ, I 'am aware that I have to use async / await functions , but I don't know how!! I've tried something like this: var response = await postToURL({......}); , but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should return Promise

```js
return await httpClient.request(uri, options).then(/* */).catch(/* */);
```

Read more about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).